# How do i tunnel multiple dynamic SSE connections from my back-end through an Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, server-sent-events

i have a backend server that listens to `SSE` connections on port `5001`
once a call is being made and the connection is initialized, the backend server will chose an available port between the range of `5010-6000` and send a redirect response to the client, this is working well i try not to change this architecture.

now i want to add an `Nginx` reverse proxy in front of this server but when the client connects, the redirect request arrives with the `localhost` URL (probably of the nginx) and of course the remote client cannot connect there.

is there a way to maintain the "real" IP address of the back-end server in the response? or maybe another way to achieve this?

i have tried to mess around with various nginx flags and headers but i don't have a lead on which direction i should focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so apparently you can set a regex in nginx location:

```
location ~ ^/path/to/sse/([^/]+) {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:$1;
```

this will forward the request to the port requested